# Selenium Standalone + Chrome driver, add capabilities from command line

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-rc

I want to run some test using selenium standalone server on Google Chrome but i need to pass some ChromeOptions to the chrome driver from command line

Anybody has an idea of how can i do that?

Comment: Why the command line?

Comment: because I want to run tests without a line of code! like this: `java  -jar ./selenium-server-2.42.2.jar -htmlSuite "*googlechrome" http://www.example.com TestSuit.html  result.html`

Comment: `TestSuit.html` is still code!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Core, which is what you are referring to, was released before Chrome existed. Support for Chrome was added later. What you are asking for was never supported, and with Selenium Core deprecated several years back, it will probably never be supported.

One possible workaround is to set the desired options in the Chrome profile.

Another options, although much more painful, is to [move up to Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.jsp#migrating-to-webdriver-reference).